# Wordpress SMOF global data declaration need twice

Tags: wordpress, global

I add `<?php global $smof_data;?>`
in header.php file and displaying data from footer.php file.

```
    <?php if($smof_data['fb_link']): ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $smof_data['fb_link']  ); ?>">Facebook</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But data is not displaying.

If i add `<?php global $smof_data;?>` in footer.php file then data displayed. Why global data declaration need twice?

Answer (score 0):

In This case your global variable may be uses in any function or the declaration may be in function,
you can't use this variable in function using declare outside of function or same can't use outside of function using declare in function.

In this condition you have to re-declare this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing with SMOF

and used the following code and it worked perfectly

```
if(!empty($data['facebook_head_url']))
    {
        $faceicon='<li><a href='.$data['facebook_head_url']; 
        $faceicon .='><span class="foundicon-facebook"> </span></a></li>';
        echo $faceicon;
    }
```